# Why does my slider get wider in mobile browser?

Tags: css, wordpress, slider

I have got an slider in my wordpress built webshop.
But i mobile browser it gets wider than it should and cat figure it out.
If you tu'ilt the fonte it gets the right width again..

You can find the site at www.starstrucked.se

Thankful for al tips.

Comment: the slider you have used is not responsive, try to use some responsive slider

Answer (score 0):

Your slider has a fixed width, which makes it too wide for the mobile browsers (such as iPhone). You could force the page to fit in the browser window by adding this to the `head` of your pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

The alternative is to find a more responsive slider script, of which there are quite a few these days, such as bxSlider.

EDIT: I see you have a script in the `head` that is meant to scale the layout on iPhone/iPad etc., but it isn't working. I would go with CSS and the meta element anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The  has a flexible width. For the desktop it's 83% (883px)
When you resize your browsers the slider has a inline-style:

```
<div class="slider jquery-slider default" style="width: 883px; height: 361px;">
<div class="slide-wrapper" style="width: 883px; height: 361px;">
```

So possibly javascript is setting the inline style or it's hardcoded in the html.
It's possible to put jquerySlider to responsive ?

http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/jquery-slider

**Extra:**
Check the console:

Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. www.starstrucked.se:63
    Viewport argument value "4.0;" for key "maximum-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated.

Solution

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```